# Getting mySQL database to google maps

Tags: php, mysql

I have only basics about coding, and wanna make a web-service via google map API
I've made up my database through mySQL, and following google tutorial for loading my data on google map

But cannot escape from error massage and here is my code.
Please check it out

```
<?php
require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysqli_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Please change the title to only contain the issue at hand. Remove any extra "hi"  etc + make it _clear_. Right now it's super unclear what you mean.